# Is it true that $\cos(x^2) \leq \cos(x \log x) \leq \cos(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, inequality

Why is this inequality true?

> $\cos(x^2) \leq \cos(x  \log x) \leq \cos(x)$.

Thanks,

Comment: The inequality isn't true...let $x$ be any number between $0$ and $1$, then $0 < x^2 < x < 1$ and cos is strictly decreasing on such an interval.

Comment: It doesn't seem true - consider $x=\sqrt{2\pi}$.

Comment: On what domain? Clearly it isn't true for all $x$: http://tinyurl.com/ld2f3sk

Comment: $\cos^2 x\leq \cos x$?

Comment: @Suzu Hirose: not when $\cos x$ is negative

Comment: ...hmm not even true for x strictly greater than 1?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, everyone :). I will ignore this incorrect inequality...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following illustrates the three curves for positive $x$.  They cross.
[image]

Comment: Nice graph, @henry - thanks so much.  Do you think the inequality holds for x >1?

Comment: @Lebron James: The short inequality holds when the green line is above the blue line, and the long inequality holds when the green line is above the red line above the blue line.  In both cases this is "sometimes".  For example $\cos(x^2) \lt \cos(x)$ when $1 \lt x \lt 2$.

Comment: Ok - got it.  Thanks again, @henry.  Have a great night :)